# How to get printf messages in NetBeans in debug mode and the Build target is RaspberryPi?

Tags: c, debugging, netbeans, raspberry-pi, netbeans-8

I am using NetBeans to debug C codes from IDE in my Windows 10 labtop and my build host is a Raspberry Pi.
When I compile and run the program, and after the program finishes, I can see the printf messages in Output. but when I step through the codes in debugging mode, I couldnot see any printf messages.

I have tried to set the stdout buffer to null and fflush. It does not work for me.

How can I get the printf working while stepping through my c codes? Thanks in advance!

This is my working environment.

IDE: NetBeans IDE 8.2 RC
Host OS: Windows 10
Build Host: RaspberryPi 4 (ssh server)

This is the C program.

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0); 

    printf("Buffered, will be flushed\r\n");
    fflush(stdout);

    printf("Buffered, will be flushed\r\n");
    fflush(stdout);

    printf("Buffered, will be flushed\r\n");
    fflush(stdout);

    printf("Buffered, will be flushed\r\n");
    fflush(stdout);
    
    fprintf(stderr, "I will be printed immediately\r\n");
    
    fprintf(stderr, "I will be printed immediately\r\n");
    
    fprintf(stderr, "I will be printed immediately\r\n");
    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
    
}
```

Comment: OT: You should not need the carriage-return. The library will translate newlines into carriage-return/newlines sequences if needed.

Comment: remote GDB works. but still not from the IDE.